# How to insert multiple tables using asp.net core web api?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a question. I want to add multiple tables at once.I've searched the web and most of them are asp.net, what I need is asp.net core.Where should I start? Can you give me some advice? Pls.

Comment: Do you mean you want to insert multiple table at one query?  Or else? Could you please tell me what's the ORM library you have used? EF core or Ado.net?

Comment: Yes,I want to insert multiple table at one query. I using ef core @BrandoZhang

Comment: I'm so sorry. My question is unclear.@BrandoZhang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear. What are you trying to do? Migrate multiple models to DB? If so, add the models to your `DbContext` and run `add-migration` in your package manager. When the migrations are created run `update-database`. This should create tables for as many models as you added to the `DbContext`.

If you're trying to insert data into multiple tables in one request maybe you should take a look at some documentation.

Check this out, it might be helpful
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data